# Why table height is bigger than the sum of cells heigh?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if my question is simple or naive, but I am still learning javascript, so be lenient with me.

One of my exercise was to create a DIV element with a specific width and height and then using javascript I tried to generate table inside this DIV. I thought that this is a simple problem, just take parent div width and height and divide it by the number of columns and rows. What I found is that in horizontal direction this works fine, but in vertical direction table height is bigger than the sum of cells heigh.

Let say that div height is 407px. This means that cell height (assuming 15 rows) should be 27,13px. The total height of the table should be 15*27,13=407px. But `table.clientWidth` gives me 420px in chrome and 453px in IE10.

I thought about borders which may be taken into account, but why then I get right width? I tried to use `getComputedStyle()` method instead `element.clientWidth` but the results were the same. Then I have read about logical vs physical pixels, but this was not helpful. I don't understand why this code behaves in this way? What I am missing?

**My HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

**My JavaScript**

```
var createGrid = function(rows, cols, appendToID){
  var appendTo = document.getElementById(appendToID); 
  var appendToWidth = appendTo.clientWidth;  
  var appendToHeight = appendTo.clientHeight;  
  var cellWidth = (appendToWidth-16)/cols;  
  var cellHeight = appendToHeight/rows;
  var table = document.createElement('table');  
  for(var i=1; i<=rows; i++){
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=1; j<=cols; j++){
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.style.background = 'white';
      cell.style.padding = '0px';
      cell.style.margin = '0px';
      cell.style.border = "1px solid blue";
      cell.style.width = cellWidth+"px";
      cell.style.height = cellHeight+"px";
      row.appendChild(cell);
      console.log("all ok");
    }    
    table.appendChild(row);    
  }
  table.style.borderCollapse = "collapse";
  table.style.border = '1px';
  appendTo.appendChild(table);
}
createGrid(15, 11, "target");
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4h83tu2j/16/)

Comment: Actually, every cell has 21px height, but has also border. The table height is: 21px * 20 cells +21px.

Answer (score 1):

The real height of the table is: 21px * 20 cells + 21px(the borders) =441px. You have the value 21px for the borders because you added     `border-collapse: collapse;` for the table. Without this, the height is 502px.

Answer (score 0):

put the height to the row instead of the cell :

```
row.style.height = cellHeight+"px";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4h83tu2j/17/

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed related to the `border` adding to the size of your divs. I suggest you take a look at the css-property `box-sizing`, most particularly its `border-box` value. This adjusts the size related to the border you have set on it.

Adding it to your cell like so: `cell.style['box-sizing'] = 'border-box';` and you will see a totally different result. The height of the cell should now take into account the border you have set on it. And thus make the cells fit the total height of your table.

You can find more information related to the border and the box-model [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).